# CSS position is making image preview half visible

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project and I am using woocommerce dynamic gallery pro plugin to preview product images in product page. but the issue is that the preview image is showing half in IE.

please can you guys check the following link in IE and help me to fix.

http://www.joannelouise.com/shop/sexy-ladies-red-embellished-dress/

I find a fix, but I am not understanding how i apply this.

I notice if i remove the position from the following class, it may fix the error. but when i am giving position some value like absolute, relative, fixed, static or even inherit. it isn't giving any response until i off the position.

so guys kindly help me to fix this.

following are my changes. which are effecting 50%.

```
.ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-image {
    overflow: visible !important;
    position: inherit !important;
}
```

but position thing is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really avoid so many inline styles. It makes for messy code and more work.

For some reason you're setting `.ad-image` to `{top: 179px;}`. Try this (after removing the inline top statement):

```
.ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-image {
    top: 0;
}
```

Strangely, I see `{top: .5px}` in Firefox. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: mate its plugin inline css... i am not adding any inline css in it

Comment: That would explain why it's different from one browser to the next. Might be time for a better plugin. Good luck.

Comment: `top: 0 !important;` i added `!important` to override. thank you mate

Comment: The plugin appears to be adding an inline style...`<div class="ad-image" style="left: 0px; top: 179px; width: 357px; height: 0px;">`   Using a CSS style as with `!important` is overriding this style.  Also note, you have a width issue.  Change the size of your page... the image will overlap your other content because the image isn't using `width:100%` properly.  I would think this might be a plugin issue too.

Comment: yes its all plugin issue, what do you suggest me to do for image width

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on a widows box right now, but it could be a case of not clearing a float or a parent item isn't containing children who are floated.

Try using:
overflow:auto on the parent container of whatever images are not showing fully. Can also try using overflow:hidden to achieve the same but avoid scrolling bars in some instances.

Try to avoid ever using !important on production sites if possible.

Comment: **"...avoid ever using !important..."** That's twice in the last week I've heard this. Can someone explain why this is popping up as a "best practice"? And then explain why `!important` is in the spec?

Comment: The reason it's not desirable to use is because you can't easily override such rules in a sheet. You have to create bad chains for specificity. Check this: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: I think folks are skimming the text too fast. Even the article you pointed me to promotes the use of `!important` -- it just says to use it correctly, rather than being lazy about specificity. Take his `.last` class example. Or something like this: `.corporate-red`, `.company-font`. Sorry, dude. My question stands.

Comment: Yikes, that's amazing. So here it is: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules

"This CSS feature improves accessibility of documents by giving users with special requirements (large fonts, color combinations, etc.) control over presentation."

However, just because it 'does' work doesn't mean one should. When one inherits a beast of a site, normally screwed up by some CMS, it 'may' be the easiest, which really just means the fastest way to override. But in general practice, it shouldn't be used from the outset of a new design.

Answer (score 0):

OP, What version of IE are you using?

> The position property specifies the type of positioning method used for an element (static, relative, absolute or fixed).
>
> **Note:** The value "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports "inherit".

Via http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

IE 7/8 Work-around:

```
.ad-gallery .ad-image-wrapper .ad-image {
    overflow: visible !important;
   position: <whatever-the-parent-is> !important;
}
```

Since IE 7/8 doesn't understand to `inherit` the position from the element's parent, you can create a CSS rule that specifies what `position` you'd like the element to use.